# How to retrieve and display images from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, file, file-upload

I just want to retrieve display images from SQL data base but I can't.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM two_upload_pics";
$myData = mysql_query($sql);

while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($myData))
{
    $img=$record["upload_image"];
    print_r($img)
    ?>

    <img src ="uploads/<?php echo $img; ?> style="height: 200px;" class="img-resposive">
    <?php
} 

?>
```

Comment: Is the image available on `uploads/` directory ?

Comment: Use MySQLi or PDO extension. Ref - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338. ```mysql``` extension is already deprectaed.

Comment: missing ending " in src attribute

Comment: Just for clarification, which RDBSM you using? Is it SQLServer or MySQL ?

Comment: The code about is missing a connection call, so will not work as it stands. What version of PHP are you using Parker?

Answer (score 0):

I've just modified your code. Try this one. Maybe it'll work.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM two_upload_pics";
$myData = mysql_query($sql);

while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($myData))
{
    $img=$record["upload_image"];

    echo "<img src ='uploads/$img' style='height: 200px;' class='img-resposive' >";
}
?>
```

**Still, I'll not suggest to use `mysql` extension. Go with `PDO or MySQLi`**